# My Discord music bot is not working as intended

Tags: python, discord, bots

Hello I tried making a Discord bot with ChatGPT for funn and dont have any knowledge of Python. Can anybody tell me what the problem with my code is.

So the bot runs normal and vs Code is not giving me any errors but if i type *play url... in my discord nothing happens.

this is my Code:

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*', intents=intents)

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, query):
voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
if not voice_channel:
await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
return

```
permissions = voice_channel.permissions_for(ctx.me)
if not permissions.connect or not permissions.speak:
    await ctx.send("I don't have permission to join or speak in that voice channel.")
    return

voice_client = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

if not voice_client:
    await voice_channel.connect()
    voice_client = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL() as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(query, download=False)
    url = info['url']
    title = info['title']

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, **ffmpeg_options), after=lambda e: print(f'Finished playing: {e}'))

await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {title}')
```

bot.run('my token')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as [Peterrrrrrr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111843/peterrrrrrr) said you need to format your code right and dont use chat gpt since its data is limited and it provides too much errors. I made some changes to your code so it can join the voice channel when a user is already in a voice channel. If not the user gets a message. For the playing part i also made some changes, but you will most likely get a error since youtube_dl isnt working anymore due to a youtube update, so uninstall youtube_dl with `pip uninstall youtube_dl` then install the master branch from github with `pip install git+https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl.git@master#egg=youtube_dl` (you need git for this, download it [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads)). In order to let the bot play music you need to install `PyNaCl` and `discord.py[voice]`. Also make sure to install `asyncio` we need this for the music part.

```
pip install PyNaCl
pip install discord.py[voice]
pip install asyncio
```

Last but not least you need a ffmpeg executable on your computer. Download ffmpeg [here](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases). Extract the zip and search for ffmpeg.exe inside the bin folder then move it to the same directory where your bot file is located.
Here is your updated code with comments:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True #needed for your bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='*', intents=intents)
#These are options for the youtube dl, not needed actually but are recommended
ytdlopts = { 
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': 'downloads/%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0',  
    'force-ipv4': True,
    'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
    'cachedir': False
    
    }

ffmpeg_options = {
        'options': '-vn'
    }

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdlopts)


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, query):
    
    try:
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel #checking if user is in a voice channel
    except AttributeError:
        return await ctx.send("No channel to join. Make sure you are in a voice channel.") #member is not in a voice channel

    permissions = voice_channel.permissions_for(ctx.me)
    if not permissions.connect or not permissions.speak:
        await ctx.send("I don't have permission to join or speak in that voice channel.")
        return
    
    voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client
    if not voice_client:
        await voice_channel.connect()
        voice_client = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url=query, download=False)) #extracting the info and not downloading the source

    
    title = data['title'] #getting the title
    song = data['url'] #getting the url

    if 'entries' in data: #checking if the url is a playlist or not
            data = data['entries'][0] #if its a playlist, we get the first item of it

    try:
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=song,**ffmpeg_options, executable="ffmpeg")) #playing the audio
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {title}') #sending the title of the video


bot.run('my token')
```

I've tested this code and it should work for you. If there are any errors etc. let me know.

Comment: So he can now join the channel and he is saying, now playing... but then nothing happens. I didnt really understand what i have to do with the ffmpeg.exe i just made a folder on my desktop and put it in there with the python code. Then i executed the ffmpeg.exe (also with administrator) a window opend and right away closed again. Thatis the error message in the VS code Terminal: (next comment)

Comment: (INFO     discord.voice_client Connecting to voice...
2023-03-07 23:23:55 INFO     discord.voice_client Starting voice handshake... (connection attempt 1)
2023-03-07 23:23:55 INFO     discord.voice_client Voice handshake complete. Endpoint found milan11.discord.media
ffmpeg was not found.)

Comment: you dont need to open the exe it should only be in the same diectory where your bot file is located the error however means that it couldnt find the exe so make sure its in the same directory or you can add it to the system variables of your computer. If you dont know how this works see this [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ffmpeg-windows#ftoc-heading-4)

Comment: hey @boez i am using the code you have above and i'm running into the issue of the song being cut short and the quality not being as sharp. I am getting this error in my terminal: 

[matroska,webm @ 0x7fffe9160340] Read error
[tls @ 0x7fffe921edc0] The specified session has been invalidated for some reason.

any thoughts?

Comment: Well its not really a problem with the code, however when you stream audio from youtube you have to accept to get this kind of error frequently, a workaround for this would be to download the audio directly and then listen to it. But this will actually slow down your bot, if you plan to use it in multiple servers.

Comment: my understanding is that this is done through ffmpeg? plz correct me if i'm wrong. i don't see it being a problem as i'm really only running this on one server. just as long as i'm able to delete it so i'm not taking too much space on my vm's storage. any thoughts here?

Comment: Ffmpeg is only for playing the Audio. So its really depending on YouTube if youre getting blocked by them or get any errors, cause streaming links expire after a short time and the code i provided above doesnt have the functionality to actually renew these streaming links, so therefore the audio stops as you described earlier.